# Using sweet alert toast for error handling in vuex

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, toast, sweetalert

I have installed `sweet alert` on my project.
Now i want to use it in `Vuex actions` but it does not work.

```js
update({ commit, dispatch }, data) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const res = await update(data);
      resolve(res.data)
      this.app.$toast('this is a test toas', {
        title: 'Test'
      })
    } catch (err) {
      this.app.$toast('this is a test toas', {
        title: 'Test'
      })
      reject(err.response);
    }
  })
},
```

It works fine in components but i can not access it with `this.app.$toast`

Answer (score 1):

The $toast is only available in `component` Scope not `vuex`, I had an issue like that before and I passed this as a reference parameter to toast.

```js
update({ commit, dispatch }, {data , that}) {
return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
  try {
    const res = await update(data);
    resolve(res.data)
    that.$toast('this is a test toas', {
      title: 'Test'
    })
  } catch (err) {
    that.$toast('this is a test toas', {
      title: 'Test'
    })
    reject(err.response);
  }
})
```

while calling the `update` method from component pass this reference as

```js
update({
  data,
  that: this
})
```

Comment: but I will still suggest using promise and handling the toast from the component.